# Create a custom mysql JOIN query in Zen Cart

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

I am trying to the product's quantity and what attribute name was selected by the user. For example, what attribute name was chosen for `product id = 180` where the `order id = 2118` ?

any suggestion how I can right mysql join query for retrieve order data.

Comment: please post your database schema nd your expected result

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle problems like this is to break the query down into steps.

In Zen Cart, the attributes details for an order are stored in the table `orders_products_attributes`. (NOTE: I am assuming your tables have the prefix `zen_`.  If they don't, just remove this from the queries below.)  So in phpMyAdmin, you could use:

`SELECT * FROM`zen_orders_products_attributes`where orders_id = 2118`

This gives you all attributes but instead of a product id, you get an orders_products_id.  So to map that back to a product_id, check the `orders_products` table.

`SELECT * FROM`zen_orders_products`where orders_id = 2118`

So now you can see that both tables contain `orders_products_id` and `orders_id`.
So use those two fields in your query.  I'm going to guess that the fields  `products_options` and `products_options_values` have the information you need.

`SELECT products_options, products_options_values FROM zen_orders_products op, zen_orders_products_attributes opa WHERE op.orders_id = opa.orders_id AND op.orders_id = 2118 AND op.products_id=180`;